# GraphQL Custom Directives

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

In the GraphQL Apollo server documentation, in the section for custom directives, we have this code:

```
const typeDefs = `#graphql
  directive @auth(requires: Role = ADMIN) on OBJECT | FIELD_DEFINITION

  enum Role {
    ADMIN
    REVIEWER
    USER
  }

  type User @auth(requires: USER) {
    name: String
    banned: Boolean @auth(requires: ADMIN)
    canPost: Boolean @auth(requires: REVIEWER)
  }
`;
```

My question is that to query for the [banned] field in [User], we must be an [ADMIN], but to access the [User] type in general, we must be a [USER]. We cannot be both, however; there's no inheritance, it's one or the other. So how can this hold?

Here's a link: https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/security/authentication/#with-custom-directives